# Creating and validating tables without referential integrity

Tags: unit-testing, oracle-sqldeveloper, etl, database-administration

Without referential integrity how does DBA create tables ?

And

How does DEV team raise Build release without Referential Integrity ?

Comment: Why would you need referential integrity to create tables?  Create the tables and either omit the foreign key constraints or create them disabled.  I don't understand what you mean by "raise Build release" or how that would relate to foreign keys.  Perhaps it would be helpful to illustrate for us exactly what problem you have in one or both cases.

Comment: By omitting the foreign keys , how will the developer come to know which is the dimension table (parent table ) and which is the fact table (child table ) and how does he develop the datawarehouse

Comment: By looking at the documentation?  By looking at the table names?  By looking at the table definitions?  But how does that relate to either of the questions in your actual question?